# Text and Images become Blurry under 768px

Tags: css

I have never encountered this problem before. Images are crisp in breakpoints larger than 768px but become blurry at the mobile breakpoint anyone have an idea what could be going on?

Site is here: http://staging.asla.org/newsustainablelandscapes/index.html

```
<div id="home-container">

<header class="clearfix">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle offcanvas-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target="#js-bootstrap-offcanvas" style="float: left;">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle Button</span>
MENU
</button>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-offcanvas navbar-offcanvas-touch navbar-offcanvas-fade" role="navigation" id="js-bootstrap-offcanvas">
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle offcanvas-toggle pull-right" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target="#js-bootstrap-offcanvas" style="float: left;">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" id="logo" href="http://www.asla.org"><img src="images/Logo.png"></a>
      </div>
      <div id="nav-container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="dropdown">
          <li class="dropdown cases studies">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" id="main-nav">Case Studies</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column cases-body studies-drop cols" role="menu">
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href="#">U.S. Mid-Atlantic</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <p class="category-cases"><a href="sidwell.html">Sidwell Friends School</a></p>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href="#">U.S. Northeast</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <p class="category-cases"><a href="bryantpark.html">Bryant Park</a></p>
                  <p class="category-cases"><a href="brownfield.html">From Brownfield to Greenfield</a></p>
                  <p class="category-cases"><a href="gowanus.html">Gowanus Canal Sponge Park&trade;</a></p>
                  <p class="category-cases"><a href="highline.html">High Line Park</a></p>
                  <p class="category-cases"><a href="lilylake.html">Lily Lake Residence</a></p>
                  <p class="category-cases"><a href="trid.html">Transit Revitalization Investment District (TRID) Master Plan</a></p>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href="#">U.S. Northwest</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <p class="category-cases"><a href="highpoint.html">High Point</a></p>
                  <p class="category-cases"><a href="raingarden.html">Mount Tabor Middle School Rain Garden</a></p>
                  <p class="category-cases"><a href="greenstreet.html">NE Siskiyou Green Street </a></p>
                  <p class="category-cases"><a href="greenroof.html">Washington Mutual Center Green Roof</a></p>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href="#">U.S. Midwest</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <p class="category-cases"><a href="greensburg.html">Greensburg Sustainable Comprehensive Plan</a></p>
                  <p class="category-cases"><a href="discovery.html">James Clarkson Environmental Discovery Center</a></p>
                  <p class="category-cases"><a href="kresge.html">Kresge Foundation Headquarters</a></p>
                  <p class="category-cases"><a href="rooftophaven.html">Rooftop Haven for Urban Agriculture</a></p>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href="#">U.S. West</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <p class="category-cases"><a href="cas.html">California Academy of Sciences</a></p>
                  <p class="category-cases"><a href="caltech.html">California Institute of Technology Master Plan</a></p>
                  <p class="category-cases"><a href="crackgarden.html">The Crack Garden</a></p>
                  <p class="category-cases"><a href="gardengarden.html">Garden/Garden &mdash; A Comparison in Santa Monica</a></p>
                  <p class="category-cases"><a href="geos.html">Geos Net Zero Energy Neighborhood</a></p>
                  <p class="category-cases"><a href="nuevaschool.html">Nueva School </a></p>
                  <p class="category-cases"><a href="cannerylofts.html">Pacific Cannery Lofts</a></p>
                  <p class="category-cases"><a href="transwater.html">Transformative Water</a></p>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href="#">U.S. Southeast</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <p class="category-cases"><a href="vietvillage.html">Viet Village Urban Farm</a></p>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href="#">U.S. Southwest</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <p class="category-cases"><a href="sonoran.html">Underwood Family Sonoran Landscape Laboratory</a></p>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href="#">Canada</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <p class="category-cases"><a href="hto.html">HtO Park</a></p>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href="#">Europe</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <p class="category-cases"><a href="cradletocradle.html">Park 20/20: A Cradle to Cradle Inspired Master Plan</a></p>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href="#">Asia</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <p class="category-cases"><a href="chongae.html">ChonGae Canal Point Source Park</a></p>
                  <p class="category-cases"><a href="ecolodge.html">Crosswaters Ecolodge</a></p>
                  <p class="category-cases"><a href="redribbon.html">The Red Ribbon, Tanghe River Park</a></p>
                </ul>
            </li>   
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown cases videos">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="videos.html" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="main-nav">Animations</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu cases-body videos-drop">
            <p style="padding-top:15px;" class="category-cases"><a href="Vid_Waste.html">Building a Park Out of Waste</a></p>
            <p class="category-cases"><a href="Vid_ActiveLiving.html">Designing for Active Living</a></li>
            <p class="category-cases"><a href="Vid_Wildlife.html">Designing Neighborhoods for People and Wildlife</a></p>
            <p class="category-cases"><a href="Vid_UrbanAg.html">The Edible City</a></li>
            <p class="category-cases"><a href="Vid_Energy.html">Energy Efficient Home Landscapes</a></p>
            <p class="category-cases"><a href="Vid_Brownfields.html">From Industrial Wasteland to Community Park</a></p>
            <p class="category-cases"><a href="Vid_Infrastructure.html">Infrastructure for All</a></p>
            <p class="category-cases"><a href="Vid_WaterManagement.html">Leveraging the Landscape to Manage Water</a></p>
            <p class="category-cases"><a href="Vid_Parks.html">Revitalizing Communities with Parks</a></p>
            <p class="category-cases"><a href="Vid_UrbanForests.html">Urban Forests = Cleaner, Cooler Air</a></p>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown cases educations">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="education.html" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="main-nav">Education</a>
          <ul style="padding-right:0;" class="dropdown-menu cases-body educations-drop">
            <p style="padding-top:15px; " class="category-cases"><a href="Ed_Brownfields.html">Brownfield Restoration / Ecosystem Rehabilitation</a></p>
            <p class="category-cases"><a href="Ed_ActiveLiving.html">Design for Active Living</a></p>
            <p class="category-cases"><a href="Ed_Wildlife.html">Designing for Biodiversity</a></p>
            <p class="category-cases"><a href="Ed_Energy.html">Energy Efficiency</a></p>
            <p class="category-cases"><a href="Ed_WaterManagement.html">Green Infrastructure</a></p>
            <p class="category-cases"><a href="Ed_Waste.html">Incorporating Sustainable Materials</a></p>
            <p class="category-cases"><a href="Ed_Infrastructure.html">Transforming Transportation Infrastructure</a></p>
            <p class="category-cases"><a href="Ed_UrbanAg.html">Urban Agriculture</a></p>
            <p class="category-cases"><a href="Ed_UrbanForests.html">Urban Forestry</a></p>
            <p class="category-cases"><a href="Ed_Parks.html">Urban Parks</a></p>
          </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  </nav>
  </header>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   <div id="header">
    <div class="title"><a href="index.html">
     <span class="design">DESIGNING OUR FUTURE:</span>&nbsp;
      <span class="sustainable">SUSTAINABLE LANDSCAPES</span></a></div>
     </div>
  <div class="thumbnail-bar">
    <a class="textleft prev disabled">View Previous</a>
    <a class="textright next">View More</a>
  </div>


<!-- THUMBNAILS -->

        <div class="scrollable">
          <div class="thumbnails">
            <!--row 1 1st slide-->
            <div class="thumb"><span>30 case studies illustrate the transformative effects of sustainable landscape design.</span></div>
            <div class="thumb"><a href="cas.html"><span><p class="title">California Academy of Sciences</p><p class="index-title-city">San Francisco, California, U.S.A.</p></span><img src="images/home/CAS.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="thumb"><a href="chongae.html"><span><p class="title">ChonGae Canal Point Source Park</p><p class="index-title-city">Seoul, South Korea</p></span><img src="images/home/ChonGae.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="thumb"><a href="sidwell.html"><span><p class="title">Sidwell Friends School</p><p class="index-title-city">Washington, D.C., U.S.A</p></span><img src="images/home/Sidwell.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="thumb"><a href="gowanus.html"><span><p class="title">Gowanus Canal Sponge Park&trade;</p><p class="index-title-city">Brooklyn, New York, U.S.A.</p></span><img src="images/home/Gowanus.jpg"></a></div>

            <div class="clear"></div>
            <!--row 2 1st slide-->               
            <div class="thumb"><a href="geos.html"><span><p class="title">Geos Net Zero Energy Neighborhood</p><p class="index-title-city">Arvada, Colorado, U.S.A.</p></span><img src="images/home/Geos.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="thumb"><a href="ecolodge.html"><span><p class="title">Crosswaters Ecolodge</p><p class="index-title-city">Nankun Mountain Reserve, Guangdong Province, China</p></span><img src="images/home/Ecolodge.jpg"></a></div>
            <!--double wide-->
            <div class="movie"><img src="images/home/VideosHeader_Orange.png"><p style="padding:10px 25px 0px 25px;">Watch animations created with Google Sketchup to learn how sustainable design works.
            <a class="non" href="videos.html"></a></p></div>
            <div class="thumb"><a href="discovery.html"><span><p class="title">James Clarkson Environmental Discovery Center</p><p class="index-title-city">White Lake Township, Michigan, U.S.A.</p></span><img src="images/home/Discovery.jpg"></a></div>

            <div class="clear"></div>
            <!--row 3 1st slide-->
            <div class="thumb"><a href="about.html"><span><img src="images/home/about.jpg"></span><img src="images/home/about.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="thumb"><a href="gardengarden.html"><span><p class="title">Garden/Garden &mdash; A Comparison in Santa Monica</p><p class="index-title-city">Santa Monica, California, U.S.A.</p></span><img src="images/home/GardenGarden.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="thumb"><a href="education.html"><span><img src="images/home/Education.jpg"></span><img src="images/home/Education.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="thumb"><a href="lilylake.html"><span><p class="title">Lily Lake Residence</p><p class="index-title-city">Dalton, Pennsylvania, U.S.A.</p></span><img src="images/home/LilyLake.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="thumb"><a href="caltech.html"><span><p class="title">California Institute of Technology Master Plan</p><p class="index-title-city">Pasadena, California, U.S.A.</p></span><img src="images/home/CalTech.jpg"></a></div>
          </div>

          <div class="thumbnails">
            <!--row 1 2nd slide-->
            <div class="thumb"><a href="cradletocradle.html"><span><p class="title">Park 20/20: <br>A Cradle to Cradle Inspired Master Plan</p><p class="index-title-city">Haarlemmermeer, Netherlands</p></span><img src="images/home/2020Cradle.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="thumb"><a href="highpoint.html"><span><p class="title">High Point</p><p class="index-title-city">Seattle, Washington, U.S.A.</p></span><img src="images/home/Highpoint_Index.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="thumb"><a href="bryantpark.html"><span><p class="title">Bryant Park</p><p class="index-title-city">New York City, <br>New York, U.S.A.</p></span><img src="images/home/BryantPark.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="thumb"><a href="rooftophaven.html"><span><p class="title">Rooftop Haven for Urban Agriculture</p><p class="index-title-city">Chicago, Illinois, U.S.A.</p></span><img src="images/home/RooftopHaven.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="thumb"><a href="greenstreet.html"><span><p class="title">NE Siskiyou Green Street</p><p class="index-title-city">Portland, Oregon, U.S.A.</p></span><img src="images/home/SiskiyouSt_Index.jpg"></a></div>

            <div class="clear"></div>
            <!--row 2 2nd slide-->
            <div class="thumb"><a href="cannerylofts.html"><span><p class="title">Pacific Cannery Lofts</p><p class="index-title-city">Oakland, California, U.S.A.</p></span><img src="images/home/CanneryLofts.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="thumb"><a href="brownfield.html"><span><p class="title">From Brownfield to Greenfield</p><p class="index-title-city">Wellesley, Massachusetts, U.S.A.</p></span><img src="images/home/WellesleyCollege_Index.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="thumb"><a href="greensburg.html"><span><p class="title">Greensburg Sustainable Comprehensive Plan</p><p class="index-title-city">Greensburg, Kansas, U.S.A.</p></span><img src="images/home/Greensburg_Index.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="thumb"><a href="trid.html"><span><p class="title">Transit Revitalization Investment District (TRID) Master Plan</p><p class="index-title-city">Philadelphia, Pennsylvania, U.S.A.</p></span><img src="images/home/TRID.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="thumb"><a href="raingarden.html"><span><p class="title">Mount Tabor Middle School Rain Garden</p><p class="index-title-city">Portland, Oregon, U.S.A.</p></span><img src="images/home/RainGarden_Index.jpg"></a></div>

            <div class="clear"></div>
            <!--row 3 2nd slide-->
            <div class="thumb"><a href="transwater.html"><span><p class="title">Transformative Water</p><p class="index-title-city">Pitkin County, Colorado, U.S.A.</p></span><img src="images/home/TransWater.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="thumb"><a href="vietvillage.html"><span><p class="title">Viet Village Urban Farm</p><p class="index-title-city">New Orleans, Louisiana, U.S.A.</p></span><img src="images/home/VietVillage_Index.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="thumb"><a href="hto.html"><span><p class="title">HtO Park</p><p class="index-title-city">Toronto, Canada</p></span><img src="images/home/HtO.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="thumb"><a href="crackgarden.html"><span><p class="title">The Crack Garden</p><p class="index-title-city">San Francisco,<br>California, U.S.A.</p></span><img src="images/home/CrackGarden_Index.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="thumb"><a href="kresge.html"><span><p class="title">Kresge Foundation Headquarters</p><p class="index-title-city">Troy, Michigan, U.S.A.</p></span><img src="images/home/Kresge.jpg"></a></div>
          </div>

          <div class="thumbnails">
            <!--row 1 3rd slide-->
              <div class="thumb"><a href="greenroof.html"><span><p class="title">Washington Mutual Center Green Roof</p><p class="index-title-city">Seattle, Washington, U.S.A.</p></span><img src="images/home/WaMuRoof_Index.jpg"></a></div>
              <div class="thumb"><a href="highline.html"><span><p class="title">High Line Park</p><p class="index-title-city">New York City, <br>New York, U.S.A.</p></span><img src="images/home/Highline_Index.jpg"></a></div>
              <div class="thumb"><a href="redribbon.html"><span><p class="title">The Red Ribbon, Tanghe River Park</p><p class="index-title-city">Qinhuangdao City, <br>Hebei Province, China</p></span><img src="images/home/RedRibbon_Index.jpg"></a></div>
              <div class="thumb"><a href="nuevaschool.html"><span><p class="title">Nueva School</p><p class="index-title-city">Hillsborough, California, U.S.A</p></span><img src="images/home/NuevaSchool.jpg"></a></div>
              <div class="thumb"><a href="sonoran.html"><span><p class="title">Underwood Family Sonoran Landscape Laboratory</p><p class="index-title-city">University of Arizona, Tucson, Arizona, U.S.A.</p></span><img src="images/home/Sonoran.jpg"></a></div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <!--THUMBNAILS END-->

        <!--FOOTER-->


  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div id="loadMore"><p>Load more</p></div>
  <div id="showLess"><p>Show less</p></div>
  <div id="footer">
  <div class="copy">&copy;2014 American Society of Landscape Architects<br>
  <a href="mailto:info@asla.org">Contact Us</a>
  </div>

 <div class="nea"><img style="float:left; margin-right:10px;"  src="images/NEALogo.png">This Web site has been made possible through a grant by: <a target="_blank" href="http://www.nea.gov/">National Endowment for the Arts</a>      </div>

<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @j08691. Problem is I don't know where to start with this I dont know if its an html css or js issue. I am simply asking if anyone else has run into this problem before, not that others fix it for me.

Comment: Well if the question really was has anyone run into this before, it's too broad for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to the image being 162x162 at the regular size but is scaled down to 105x105 for mobile. This often causes the blurred effect because browsers are not image processors.

The solution is to create a smaller image to your liking and serve that instead using media queries, for example.

Comment: Thanks @Rob I pushed the CSS change to resize the thumbnails, I am still encountering the issue however. Strange thing is its seems to clear up at very specific points in that under 768 breakpoint

Comment: Also want to add it looks fine on a physical phone, could just be a browser rendering issue?

Comment: Thank you very much this is enough info to work off of I just got thrown this project. 

Best